# Is it possible to navigate into all folders?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

is it possible to navigate into all computer/server directories? I'm using the "public" folder to serve static files but is possible to read that files for example from the "/home/user/images" directory? (i'm using node + express).

Answer (score 1):

Reading files outside of the server folder is not possible, it may work on your local host, but when you deploy, it will get crashed.

Any files inside the server folder can be read as follows:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/home/user/images'));
```

__dirname is used so that in any case you move your file to any other folder, it still works as expected.